# Bypass field validation

Tags: 7, entities

I have a content type form with some fields attached. I'm looking for an easy way of skipping core validation for one of those fields. I guess what I'm looking for is something like this:

```
$form['foo']['#check_valid'] = FALSE;
```

This could possibly be achieved using `#limit_validation_errors`, but this would require some work. Can this be achieved without too much of a hassle?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to remove core validation from the field by adding the #form_validate array element to the form element you want to edit, then pass a custom validation callback that passes the field by default.  That should work.